# PHP Get random element out of array 1, show, and move to array 2

Tags: php, arrays, random

I'm trying to make a page that when I press a button randomly returns an element out of array1, saves it (so I can show it on the page), and then moves it to array2 so the element doesn't get returned a second time, but I have no idea where to start.

Here's the source array:

```
$subject = array ( 
    array("Title1","comment1"), 
    array("Title2","comment2"), 
    array("Title3","comment3"), 
    array("Title4","comment4"), 
);
```

Comment: echo $items[array_rand($items)];

Answer (score 1):

Try these codes:

```
<?php
shuffle( $array1 );
array_push( $array2 , array_pop($array1) );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_rand()` to randomly get a key of one element and then remove it from the first array and add it to the second array.

```
$subject = array (
    array("Title1","comment1"),
    array("Title2","comment2"),
    array("Title3","comment3"),
    array("Title4","comment4")
);

$key = array_rand($subject);
$elem = $subject[$key];
unset($subject[$key]);
$array2[] = $elem;
```